# Is there any benefit in catching different exceptions separately?

Tags: java, exception

Besides the obvious case of treating different exceptions differently, is there any benefit in treating exceptions separately? I see a lot of code that looks something among the lines of:

```
try {
    doSomethingThatMayThrowExceptions();
} catch (SomeException e) {
} catch (OtherException e) {
}
```

I always tend to just catch the generic `Exception` when I only have one exception-handling process.

A derived question would be: is it better in any way to state the exact type of exception you are catching, if it's just one? For example:

```
try {
    number = Integer.parseInt(numberString);
} catch (Exception e) {
    // ...
}
```

In the above example, the `try` block can only throw a `NumberFormatException`. Is there any downside to catching the generic `Exception` here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> In the above example, the try block can only throw a NumberFormatException. Is there any downside to catching the generic Exception here?

Not really. But it can be asked, what do you achieve by *"hiding"* the exact exception?

If you catch `NumberFormatException`, you can instantly see which exceptions are expected to be thrown.

**EDIT:** Pardon me. The above example can also throw unchecked exceptions ie. NPEs, so you're actually catching more exceptions and treating them all the same way. You might actually want to implement different exception handling for those exceptions (if you even want to catch and handle unchecked exceptions).

Answer (score 3):

Catching Exception will result in catching unchecked Exceptions as well as checked ones, possibly ones that you are not expecting. This could result in your exception handling trying to manage a situation in ways other than you are intending.

Answer (score 1):

For me it is a fact of maintenance, if you wrote an app a year ago and an exception is generated and you look at the code, it sucks to see `throws Exception`/`} catch (Exception e) {`, I then need to read all the javadocs of the code in the method to see what types of exceptions are thrown.

So I tend to catch specific types of exceptions to know what I am dealing with.
Another example could be a `SQLException`. In certain cases; depending on the `errorCode` of the sqle, i would want to retry the database operation, whereas in any other type of exception I want to abort and report.

Answer (score 0):

No, it really does come down to just making it so that you have a catch condition for different possible contingencies. As a general rule, catching just Exception is bad because some operations might cause you to need to catch an IOException and a SQLException, with very different error handling needed for each.

In most situations, you would actually want a catch block for Exception so that you have a generic error handler where you can clean things up and raise a general program error. Though that should come after specific cases in the try-catch-block.

Comment: You're advocating a catch of Exception in all your try/catch blocks?